# php curl get json response not getting all values in foreach

Tags: php, json, curl, foreach

When I get a JSON response back from the server and simply return the array, all of the data and values are pulled in correctly.
But when using a foreach loop to iterate over each object to get it's value, most of the values are missing and I'm not sure why.

curl request:

```
function get_variety_statistics($crop_id){
    $login = seedware_login();

    // request parameters
    $path = '/services/v1/getVarietyStatistics';
    $body = array(
        'sw_crop_id'    => $crop_id,
    );

    // SeedWare API request via cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://agventure20.seedware.net'.$path,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Bearer'.$login['token'],
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body)
        )
    );

    // store response as string and return it
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

output of JSON only:

```
add_shortcode( 'display_variety_statistics_raw', 'display_variety_statistics_raw' );
function display_variety_statistics_raw($atts){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'sw_crop_id'            => 0,
        'product'               => false,
        'maturity'              => false,
        'relative_maturity'     => false,
        'crm'                   => false,
        'trait'                 => false,
        'drought_type'          => false,
        'marketing_segments'    => false,
        'download'              => false, 
        'new'                   => false
    ), $atts));

    //check for results
    if ($atts['sw_crop_id'] === 0) {
        return 'No results found.';
    }
    return json_encode(get_variety_statistics($atts['sw_crop_id']));
}
```

JSON output result (for a single item):
[image: JSON output result (for a single item)]
`{"variety":"6134","variety_id":"6134","maturity":"101.00","year_released":"2015","new":"0","crop":"Corn","trait":"Conventional Corn","family":"6134","family_varieties":"","trait_logo":"","tech_sheet":"https:\/\/agventure22.seedware.net\/embed\/techSheet\/getTechSheet\/5317","Plant Height":"Medium","Ear Height":"Medium","Flex":"Medium","Girth":"","Kernel Rows Range":"16-18","Cob Color":"Red","Husk Cover":"Medium","Flowering Maturity":"Medium Early","Black Layer Maturity":"Medium","Stress Emergence":"Very Good","Drought Tolerance":"Very Good","Heat Tolerance":"","Brittle Tolerance":"Very Good","Stalk Strength":"Good","Root Strength":"Very Good","Staygreen":"Competitive","Grain Drydown":"Manage","Test Weight":"Good","Gray Leaf Spot":"Manage","Northern Leaf Blight":"Good","Southern Leaf Blight":"N\/A","Goss Wilt":"Good","Anthracnose Stalk Rot":"Data Pending","Head Smut":"Manage","Fusarium Ear Rot":"Good","Gibberella Ear Rot":"Competitive","Diplodia Ear Rot":"Data Pending","High Input":"Highly Recommended","Low Input":"Recommended","Corn after Corn":"Recommended","Limited\/No Till":"Highly Recommended","Delayed Harvest":"Highly Recommended","Silage Use":"Not Recommended","Optimum Population":"30,000-38,000","GDU to Silk":"1240.000","GDU to Black Layer":"2450.000","Fiber Digestibility":"Very Good","NEW":"","Drought Type":"","Bullet 2":"Very good stress emergence for enhanced stand establishment","Bullet 1":"101 RM hybrid with sound agronomic characteristics","Bullet 3":"Consistent performance across all environments","Bullet 4":"Good tolerance to Northern Corn Leaf Blight","Bullet 5":"","Bullet 6":"","Title Prep":"6134\u2122","HAE":"","HES":"Yes","HTF":"Yes","TFS":"No","YFC":"","Bag":"AgVenture","Product":"6134","Trait":"","Silage Yield":"Competitive","Starch and Sugar, %":"","Milk Per Ton":"Competitive","Milk Per Acre":"","Beef Per Ton":"","Beef Per Acre":"","Dual Purpose":"No","Late Silage Harvest":"","Gray Leaf Spot NEW":"Moderate Resistance","Northern Leaf Blight NEW":"Good Resistance","Tar Spot":"","Goss's Wilt NEW":"Good Resistance","Southern Leaf Blight NEW":"N\/A","Southern Rust":"","Anthracnose Stalk Rot NEW":"N\/A","Gibberella Stalk Rot":"","Fusarium Ear Rot NEW":"Good Resistance","Gibberella Ear Rot NEW":"Moderate Resistance","Diplodia Ear Rot NEW":"N\/A","Head Smut NEW":"Moderate Resistance","Early Root Strength":"","Late Root Strength":""}`

foreach loop:

```
add_shortcode( 'display_varieties_update', 'display_varieties_update' );
function display_varieties_update($atts){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'sw_crop_id'            => 0,
        'product'               => false,
        'family'                => false,
        'maturity'              => false,
        'relative_maturity'     => false,
        'crm'                   => false,
        'trait'                 => false,
        'drought_type'          => false,
        'marketing_segments'    => false,
        'download'              => false,
        'silage_use_only'       => null,
        'filter_options'        => null,
        'sort_by'               => false
    ), $atts));

    $trait_filter = $_GET['trait'];

    //check for results
    if ($atts['sw_crop_id'] === 0) {
        return 'No results found.';
    }
    $varieties = get_variety_statistics($atts['sw_crop_id']);


    //table
    $varieties_table .= "<table id='vt-table-agv' class='vt-table swcrop-{$atts['sw_crop_id']}'>";
    foreach($varieties as $variety) {
        //set maturity decimals
        $variety['maturity'] = ($atts['sw_crop_id'] == 104 ? number_format((float)$variety['maturity'], 1, '.', '') : round($variety['maturity'],0));
        $variety['Relative Maturity'] = round($variety['Relative Maturity'],0);
        $variety['CRM'] = round($variety['CRM'],0);

        if ($atts['silage_use_only'] == null || $atts['silage_use_only'] == "Dual Purpose" && $variety["Dual Purpose"] == $atts['yes']) {
                $varieties_table .= "<tr class='vt-row'>";
                $varieties_table .= "<td>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Variety:</strong> ".$variety['variety']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Variety ID:</strong> ".$variety['variety_id']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Maturity:</strong> ".$variety['maturity']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Year Released:</strong> ".$variety['year_released']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>New:</strong> ".$variety['new']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Crop:</strong> ".$variety['crop']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Trait:</strong> ".$variety['trait']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Family:</strong> ".$variety['family']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Family Varieties:</strong> ".$variety['family_varieties']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Trait Logo:</strong> ".$variety['trait_logo']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Tech Sheet:</strong> ".$variety['tech_sheet']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Plant Height:</strong> ".$variety['Plant Height']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Ear Height:</strong> ".$variety['Ear Height']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Flex:</strong> ".$variety['Flex']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Girth:</strong> ".$variety['Girth']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Kernel Rows Range:</strong> ".$variety['Kernel Rows Range']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Cob Color:</strong> ".$variety['Cob Color']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Husk Cover:</strong> ".$variety['Husk Cover']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Flowering Maturity:</strong> ".$variety['Flowering Maturity']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Black Layer Maturity:</strong> ".$variety['Black Layer Maturity']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Stress Emergence:</strong> ".$variety['Stress Emergence']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Drought Tolerance:</strong> ".$variety['Drought Tolerance']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Heat Tolerance:</strong> ".$variety['Heat Tolerance']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Brittle Tolerance:</strong> ".$variety['Brittle Tolerance']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Stalk Strength:</strong> ".$variety['Stalk Strength']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Root Strength:</strong> ".$variety['Root Strength']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Staygreen:</strong> ".$variety['Staygreen']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Grain Drydown:</strong> ".$variety['Grain Drydown']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Test Weight:</strong> ".$variety['Test Weight']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Gray Leaf Spot:</strong> ".$variety['Gray Leaf Spot']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Northern Leaf Blight:</strong> ".$variety['Northern Leaf Blight']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Southern Leaf Blight:</strong> ".$variety['Southern Leaf Blight']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Goss Wilt:</strong> ".$variety['FlGoss Wiltex']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Anthracnose Stalk Rot:</strong> ".$variety['Anthracnose Stalk Rot']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Head Smut:</strong> ".$variety['Head Smut']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Fusarium Ear Rot:</strong> ".$variety['Fusarium Ear Rot']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Gibberella Ear Rot:</strong> ".$variety['Gibberella Ear Rot']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Diplodia Ear Rot:</strong> ".$variety['Diplodia Ear Rot']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>High Input:</strong> ".$variety['High Input']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Low Input:</strong> ".$variety['Low Input']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Corn after Corn:</strong> ".$variety['Corn after Corn']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Limited/No Till:</strong> ".$variety['Limited\/No Till']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Delayed Harvest:</strong> ".$variety['Delayed Harvest']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Silage Use:</strong> ".$variety['Silage Use']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Optimum Population:</strong> ".$variety['Optimum Population']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>GDU to Silk:</strong> ".$variety['GDU to Silk']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>GDU to Black Layer:</strong> ".$variety['GDU to Black Layer']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Fiber Digestibility:</strong> ".$variety['Fiber Digestibility']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>NEW:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Drought Type:</strong> ".$variety['Drought Type']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Bullet 2:</strong> ".$variety['Bullet 2']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Bullet 1:</strong> ".$variety['Bullet 1']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Bullet 3:</strong> ".$variety['Bullet 3']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Bullet 4:</strong> ".$variety['Bullet 4']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Bullet 5:</strong> ".$variety['Bullet 5']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Bullet 6:</strong> ".$variety['Bullet 6']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Title Prep:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>HAE:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>HES:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>HTF:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>TFS:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>YFC:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Bag:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Product:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Trait:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Silage Yield:</strong> ".$variety['NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Starch and Sugar, %:</strong> ".$variety['Starch and Sugar, %']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Milk Per Ton:</strong> ".$variety['Milk Per Ton']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Milk Per Acre:</strong> ".$variety['Milk Per Acre']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Beef Per Ton:</strong> ".$variety['Beef Per Ton']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Beef Per Acre:</strong> ".$variety['Beef Per Acre']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Dual Purpose:</strong> ".$variety['Dual Purpose']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Late Silage Harvest:</strong> ".$variety['Late Silage Harvest']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Gray Leaf Spot NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Gray Leaf Spot NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Northern Leaf Blight NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Northern Leaf Blight NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Tar Spot:</strong> ".$variety['Tar Spot']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Goss's Wilt NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Goss\'s Wilt NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Southern Leaf Blight NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Southern Leaf Blight NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Southern Rust:</strong> ".$variety['Southern Rust']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Anthracnose Stalk Rot NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Anthracnose Stalk Rot NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Gibberella Stalk Rot:</strong> ".$variety['Gibberella Stalk Rot']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Fusarium Ear Rot NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Fusarium Ear Rot NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Gibberella Ear Rot NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Gibberella Ear Rot NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Diplodia Ear Rot NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Diplodia Ear Rot NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Head Smut NEW:</strong> ".$variety['Head Smut NEW']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Early Root Strength:</strong> ".$variety['Early Root Strength']."</div>";
                    $varieties_table .= "<div><strong>Late Root Strength:</strong> ".$variety['Late Root Strength']."</div>";
                
                $varieties_table .= "</td></tr>";

            //}
        }
    }
    $varieties_table .= "</table>";
    return $varieties_table;
}
```

using foreach loop (screenshot is cutoff, but anything after 'tech_sheet' is not displaying data):
[image: using foreach loop (screenshot is cutoff, but anything after 'tech_sheet' is not displaying data)]

**UPDATE:**

I've done a var_dump on the loops contents.
Missing over half of the array items that are available when you decode JSON request initially, and there's items that aren't in the original request either?

var_dump example string:

```
array(18) {
  ["variety"]=>
  string(4) "6134"
  ["variety_id"]=>
  string(4) "6134"
  ["maturity"]=>
  float(101)
  ["year_released"]=>
  string(4) "2015"
  ["new"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["crop"]=>
  string(4) "Corn"
  ["trait"]=>
  string(17) "Conventional Corn"
  ["family"]=>
  string(4) "6134"
  ["family_varieties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["trait_logo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tech_sheet"]=>
  string(66) "https://agventure22.seedware.net/embed/techSheet/getTechSheet/5317"
  ["AVI Female"]=>
  string(4) "P442"
  ["AVI Male"]=>
  string(4) "P411"
  ["Title Prep"]=>
  string(7) "6134™"
  ["Platform"]=>
  string(10) "1001674-01"
  ["Pro Name"]=>
  string(7) "6S7/6T1"
  ["Relative Maturity"]=>
  float(0)
  ["CRM"]=>
  float(0)
}
```

**AVI Female, AVI Male, Platform & Pro Name** aren't in the original JSON output request.

Comment: Almost everything after that item has a space in it which I thought might be the problem, but a [quick test](https://3v4l.org/gTrVL) shows that not to be true. Instead of building a string, try [dumping out the loop variable's contents](https://3v4l.org/ngpab) to see if you can spot anything.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've tried dumping the loop variables contents using var_dump, and now I'm missing over half the items, and some items weren't in the original JSON request? Thanks for your assistance on this! I've updated my question with the var_dump results

Comment: @ChrisHass I've tried a few different things with how the data is being pulled, and it seems the data changes when I put this function into a variable, so I can create the foreach loop: `varieties = get_variety_statistics($atts['sw_crop_id']);` ... and then call the var_dump. if I don't throw it into the variable and just do `var_dump(get_variety_statistics($atts['sw_crop_id']));` the data shows as intended. Why would that matter?

Comment: That shouldn't matter unless you are later accidentally clobbering that variable. For instance, if you accidentally had a single `=` somewhere instead of `==` or `===` for equality. Here's a demo that shows three different ways of accessing: https://3v4l.org/aRf5i. They are all functionally equivalent although some have some additional side-effects, but those aren't germane to your problem. Can you isolate this to a single JSON entry that is having this, or is it all. Here's also a version of the same problem [but with your data](https://3v4l.org/d16Ea), and it looks the same to me

Comment: could you copy the entire raw json response from the curl request prior to any other function calls to a pastebin as there is no way to test the api response for ourselves without the correct bearer token